# Execute function after async function is done

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

How to make function `extra_stuff` to be executed after `anim` or `display_effects` functions are done ? Best option would be to hold function `extra_stuff` until `animate` is done because i don't want to edit anonymous function passed to `on` method, it should stay simple and readable.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            .selected {color:pink;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <ul id="workers">
            <li><a href="#">worker#1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">worker#2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">worker#3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">worker#4</a></li>
        </ul>

        <script>

        $(function()
        {
            function unmark_selected()
            {
                $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
            }
            function mark_user(e)
            {
                e.addClass('selected');
            }

            function display_effects(e)
            {
                e.animate({ fontSize: "24px" }, 1500);
            }

            function extra_stuff()
            {
                console.log('maybe another animation');
            }

            $('ul#workers li a').on('click', function()
            {
                unmark_selected();
                mark_user( $(this) );
                display_effects( $(this) );
                extra_stuff();
            });
        });

        </script>       
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your `extra_stuff()` comment says "maybe another animation" - if in fact you do want to add additional animations to the same element they will automatically be queued.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `display_effects` to return a [promise()](http://api.jquery.com/promise/) object, and then call the `extra_stuff` method in the `done` callback of the promise

```
$(function () {
    function unmark_selected() {
        $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
    }

    function mark_user(e) {
        e.addClass('selected');
    }

    function display_effects(e) {
        return e.animate({
            fontSize: "24px"
        }, 1500).promise();
    }

    function extra_stuff() {
        console.log('maybe another animation');
    }

    $('ul#workers li a').on('click', function () {
        unmark_selected();
        mark_user($(this));
        display_effects($(this)).done(extra_stuff);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it works great but what if i want to add another functions to be executed after `display_effects`. In this solution function `extra_stuff` looks like some additional, not important code (passed as parameter). I don't want to stop adding another instructions/functions in this anonymous function just because `display_effects` function got async code. I hope you can understand me :)

Answer (score 1):

You need a callback:

```
function display_effects(e, callback) {
    e.animate({ fontSize: "24px" }, 1500, callback);
}

$('ul#workers li a').on('click', function() {
    unmark_selected();
    mark_user( $(this) );
    display_effects( $(this), extra_stuff ); // no invocation, pass reference!
});
```

It will be called in the future, when the fontsize animation is done. Check the [docs for the `.animate()` method](http://api.jquery.com/animate/). Notice that if you simply want to add another animation after the fontsize, they will be queued automatically.